# ActiveStorage without ActiveRecord rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, gridfs, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Is it possible to add `ActiveStorage`  on `rails 6` without adding `ActiveRecord` 
I am using API application having only `mongoDB` database. Now, as I have observed that `FSGrid` which actually a good option, having a database size issue and we want physical file available on `S3`.

Comment: Active storage does not support without active record. You can check the discussion here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31408#issuecomment-453823788

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it's still not possible now in April 2020.

From [Mongodb Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails/):

> At this time ActiveStorage requires ActiveRecord and is not usable with Mongoid.

[image: MongoDB Doc Image]
They are not working on it and suggest people to try to implement it with the current API as discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31408#issuecomment-454243234)